# Can I set different fonts for different lines in a tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a dictionary. And I have a list of lines (strings) of a particular word. I need it to look like this:[image]

Comment: Yes. Use tags as described in [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: Update: effbot has vanished, but you can find the pages at [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023803/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a text widget and style the dictionary elements differently:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x250')

# Create text widget
word_text = Text(root, wrap='word', padx=10, pady=10)
word_text.pack(fill='both', padx=10, pady=10)

# Define attributes for dictionary entry
word = 'mountain'
pronunciation = '[ˈmount(ə)n]'
word_class = 'noun'
description = '''a large natural elevation of the earth's surface rising abruptly from the surrounding level; a large steep hill'''

# Insert text sections
word_text.insert('end', word+'\n')
word_text.insert('end', pronunciation+'\n')
word_text.insert('end', word_class+'\n')
word_text.insert('end', description)

# Tag and style text sections
word_text.tag_add('word','1.0','1.end')
word_text.tag_config('word', font='arial 15 bold')  # Set font, size and style
word_text.tag_add('pronunciation','2.0','2.end')
word_text.tag_config('pronunciation', font='arial 13 normal')
word_text.tag_add('word_class','3.0','3.end')
word_text.tag_config('word_class', font='arial 12 italic', lmargin1=30,
                     spacing1=10, spacing3=15)  # Set margin and spacing
word_text.tag_add('description','4.0','99.end')
word_text.tag_config('description', font='none 12', lmargin1=15, lmargin2=15)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to create 4-5 labels if you want different fonts. It would be structured like:

- First label = **mountain**
- Second label = ['mauntin]
- Third label = ropa
- Fourth label = definition

Visit [Python's tkinter docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.html) for more info on font configurations for labels.